# How to correctly integrate InAppSettingsKit with Storyboard in a TabBar?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, storyboard, inappsettingskit

I have been trying for a while now, but I can't figure out how to integrate [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) in an App, that uses Storyboard and a TabBar.

I've got my tab bar defined in a Storyboard, now I want one tab to have this InAppSettingsKit as the root view. Is this possible after all?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Isn't it easier to create your own static tableview in the storyboard with the controls, and set the NSUserDefaults when a control is tapped. By doing this you do not need the InAppSettingsKit framework.

Comment: Yes, maybe, but but I prefer InAppSettingsKit because it's very similar to the settings app and because it uses a settings.bundle. If I don't get the InAppSettingsKit I will do what you said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, after trying various things, I figured out, that my problem actually was, that I put all the IASK-stuff into a static library (and I had no Settings Bundle). After moving all the code and nibs to the same project as the MainStoryboard, it worked by adding a TableView Controller to my storyboard and settings its custom class to IASKAppSettingsViewController.

Comment: I will try it if it works for me you'll have the bounty. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you want button handlers and other custom code, do following:

1. Create a class derived from UITableViewController
2. Modify the header file to derive from `IASKAppSettingsViewController
   <IASKSettingsDelegate>` Remove all methods but the initWithCoder and the
   settingsViewControllerDidEnd protocol (or make calls to super). This
   is so that the default UITableVC code doesn't override IASK
   functionality. Be sure to stick `self.delegate = self;` into the
   initWithCoder to get the buttons to work.

   ```
   //SettingsViewController.h
   #import "IASKAppSettingsViewController.h"

   @interface SettingsViewController : IASKAppSettingsViewController <IASKSettingsDelegate>
   @end


   //SettingsViewController.m
   // ...
   - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
   {
       self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
       if (self) {
           self.delegate = self;
       }
       return self;
   }

   #pragma mark -
   #pragma mark IASKAppSettingsViewControllerDelegate protocol
   - (void)settingsViewControllerDidEnd:(IASKAppSettingsViewController*)sender {
       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }
   ```
3. Set custom class of the table view in storyboard to
   your class

Comment: Just wanted to report this worked perfectly in Xode 5 / ios6/7. I have a TabBarController with a SettingsviewController as described above.